# Construct a bijection between two sets

Tags: functions

I need to construct a concrete bijection between two sets: **(-7, -6]** and **[1,3)**.

Comment: try a strictly decreasing first order one. $(ax+b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example use
$$x\mapsto -2x-11.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: consider the (half-open) line segment connecting the points $(-7,3)$ with $(-6,1)$.